# How to raise 403 Error (Forbiden) and 404 error in Odoo web controller

Tags: python, odoo

I am creating a web controller in Odoo and I want to check if the user has permission to perform an action, if it doesn't I would like to raise a 403 exception. So, how can I raise a 403 exception inside Odoo web controller?
I also want to know how to raise a 404 exception as well. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could raise any of the Werkzeug Exceptions to do what you want

https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/exceptions/

```py
import werkzeug.exceptions
from werkzeug.exceptions import (HTTPException, BadRequest, Forbidden,
                                 NotFound, InternalServerError)
```

To raise a 403:

```py
raise Forbidden()
```

To raise a 404:

```py
raise NotFound()
```

Odoo have some error handling in order to convert Odoo errors into Werkzeug Exceptions but it's easy to just use it like the examples